# encrypt a binary data into binary and also decrypt

Tags: python, python-2.7, encryption, aes

I want to encrypt a binary data into binary and then also decrypt in binary. How can I do this in python? I was trying to use `AES` but was unable to successfully do it.

```
 Key = '00000000’
 des = DES.new(key', DES.MODE_ECB)
 plain_text = "10101011"
 #encryption
 cipher_text = des.encrypt(plain_text)
 #decryption
 decrypted_pt = des.decrypt(cipher_text)
```

Answer (score 2):

You didn't specify, but your code makes it look like you're using ECB mode. Here's a short example of code I wrote for the cryptopals challenge, slightly modified to better fit your sample code. Make sure your key is 16 bytes long. Also, the plain text must be a multiple of 16 bytes. Another one of the challenges has you implementing a padding function.

Another thing to note is that after encrypting your data, the safest way to store that is in some sort of encoding, usually Base64 is used. Then when you go to decrypt it, you base64 decode the data first.

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
import base64


def ecb_encrypt(message, key):
    """ Encrypts a message in AES ECB mode with a given key
    ACCEPTS: Two strings, the plaintext message and the key
    RETURNS: A bytes string of base64 encoded ciphertext
    """

    aes = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_ECB)
    return base64.b64encode(aes.encrypt(message)).decode()


def ecb_decrypt(encrypted, key):
    """ Decrypts a ciphertext in AES ECB mode with a given key
    ACCEPTS: Two strings, the base64 encoded ciphertext and the key
    RETURNS: A bytes string of the plaintext message
    """

    aes = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_ECB)
    return aes.decrypt(base64.b64decode(encrypted))


if __name__ == "__main__":

    Key = "0000000000000000"
    plain_text = "1010101110101011"

    cipher_text = ecb_encrypt(plain_text, Key)
    decrypted_pt = ecb_decrypt(cipher_text, Key).decode()

    print("Original message: {}".format(plain_text))
    print("Encrypted message: {}".format(cipher_text))
    print("Decrypted message: {}".format(decrypted_pt))
```

Answer (score 0):

What you might be looking for is the xor bitwise operator in python.
Basically it takes every pair of bits in two numbers and returns 1 only and only if one of the bits is 1, otherwise it returns 0.

```
Input = int(raw_input('Encrypt/Decrypt this >>>'), 2) #input must be in bit format
key = 0b0100110 #'0b' indicates this is in second base
Encryption = key ^ Input
print Encryption
```

with "1101001" as an input the code will print 79 (which is 1001111)

Repeating that same process like so:

```
Decryption = key ^ Encryption
print Decryption
```

will print 105 which was our original input (105 = 1101001)

for more reading go to: https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators  or https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/bitwise_operators_example.htm

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using PyCrypto, so I'd suggest taking a look at [this blog post](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2010/06/25/aes-encryption-of-files-in-python-with-pycrypto/) which includes sample code and walks you through the process of encrypting/decrypting binary files (not worth duplicating the code here).

You might also want to check out [simple-crypt](https://github.com/andrewcooke/simple-crypt) which abstracts aways some of the tedious work in using PyCrypto.